# Как выполнить setTimeout по очереди в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, очередь, setinterval, settimeout

Я только изучаю JS, Подскажите пожалуйста, как выполнить setTimeout по очереди в JavaScript ?

У меня есть 4 функции которые выполняются по setTimeout и должны выполняться по очереди. Как это сделать ? 
Сейчас сначала выполняется та функция у которого секунды меньше остальных, что и логично.

И еще нужно сделать так, чтобы после выполнения последней функции сработал setInterval и весь процесс повторялся.

Comment: Почитайте про async-await https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как задать очередь выполнения функции в JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032432/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javascript)

Comment: так стоп, вы ж сами задали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032432/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-javascript чем вам там ответ не угодил? Вы сейчас спрашиваете по сути тоже самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Определяем функцию задержки в которую передаем время
const delay = (time) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}

// вызываем
delay(100) // через 100 мс
.then(() => {
  console.log('1 шаг');
  return delay(200) // через 200 мс
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('2й шаг');
  return delay(150) // через 150 мс
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('3й шаг');
})
// и так далее
```

При необходимости добавления новых функций просто наращиваем цепочку, добавляя новые .then(). Если задержка между ними нужна нулевая можно просто не возвращать delay(...), функции все равно будут выполнены последовательно. Такой подход гораздо удобнее чем использование callback hell, что является плохой практикой.

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало. Есть еще вопрос, задаю setInterval чтобы весь процесс повторялось каждые 10 секунд например, но есть одна маленькая проблема, как только страница загружается процесс стартует через 10 секунд, как убрать данную задержку ?

Comment: setInterval предполагает выполнение кода каждые N секунд и если вы ставите интервал в 10 секунд то первый раз он запустится через эти 10 секунд. Чтобы этого избежать вам сначала нужно выполнить нужный участок кода, а затем уже поставить интервал, чтобы он повторялся. Сделать это можно разными способами.

Comment: setInterval(function foo() {
  console.log('HI');
  return  foo;
}(), 10000);

Comment: Когда вместо console.log вставляю нужную функцию, оно не работает.

Comment: () => {
  console.log('3й шаг');
} - вот это и есть функция, вместо console.log() нужно вставлять не ссылку на функцию а сам код функции или ее вызов через круглые скобки.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timerId = setTimeout(function tick() {
  alert('tick');
  timerId = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Просто вызывайте свои функции рекурсивно через нужный интервал времени